# AJAX post form won't work. It does absolutely nothing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

There was an error in my code and there was also a js file included inside my page which prevented anything from executing inside $(document).ready(function () { ...

i'm trying to sumbit this login form:

```
<form class="form" id="AjaxForm">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <button type="submit" id="login-button">Login</button>
</form>
```

Via ajax with this code:

```
var request;
$("#AjaxForm").submit(function(event){

    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);

    // Let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
    // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
    // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    // Fire off the request to /form.php
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "login.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // Reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

    // Prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

Which i found here: [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

I'm trying to post it to login.php which checks if it is a valid username and password. But when i press the Login button it just puts the username and the password in the url and does nothing. And when i add *action="login.php" method="POST"* It submits the form but not via ajax because when i comment the ajax code out it still submits. I'm trying to prevent that. Any insights on my problem?

EDIT: lives here for now: http://5f6738d9.ngrok.io/test/public/index.html username and password are test

Comment: Check developers console

Comment: It does not say anything except 'navigated to:'

Comment: Sounds like a conflict with the jQuery library not loading. Can you ensure it's loading?

Comment: Jquery is loaded. Tested with this code window.onload = function() {
    if (window.jQuery) {  
        // jQuery is loaded  
        alert("Yeah!");
    } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
        alert("Doesn't Work");
    }
}

Comment: This might be a bit to obvious, but did you make sure your code is inside `$(document).ready(function(){..`?

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gLd5ymr9/) demo with the code you posted, and configured with jQuery 1.11.0 - there's no problem there, it works.  I've modified the two `input` fields to have closing backslashes before the last `>`.  Seems like it might be something beyond what we can see in your question.

Comment: Yes it is inside of it.

Comment: @Ross — "I've modified the two input fields to have closing backslashes before the last >" — It isn't XML, that's pointless.

Comment: @Quentin So?  I was just clarifying what I had modified - which was as a result of jsfiddle red flagging the original html.  Humble apologies if that offended you.

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button is a standard submit type button which means that your form will be submitted normally. Based on your HTML code it will just submit the form to the same URL. The JS code will not have time to execute.
All you need to do is cancel de default HTML form submit by adding

```
event.preventDefault();
```

You need to add this first thing in your submit listener.
So your JS code will start like this

```
$("#AjaxForm").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    //....
```

Try using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#AjaxForm').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        if(request){
            request.abort();
            request = false;
        }

        var $form = $(this);
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();
        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
        $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

        var request = $.ajax({
            url: 'login.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: serializedData,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // login was successful so maybe refresh the page
                window.location.reload();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // display form errors received from server
            },
            complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                request = false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So.. what exactly do you think `request.abort();` is doing...?

Comment: In case somebody clicks more then one time on the submit button the script will end up sending the request many time. The abort() can be used to stop the current AJAX request. So when you first click the submit the AJAX request will be stored in the request variable. Then if you click the button again while the AJAX is still in progress it will just abort it and start a new one.

Comment: Also be aware that request.done() is called on success or failure...so it doesn't mean the that the login was successful. You should use request.success() for successful login, request.error() for failure. Also you should delete the set the request variable to false as soon as the request is completed. Otherwise in case of an error the user will not be able to submit the form again.

Comment: I tried as you said and it doesn't work, but i've tried putting console.log('1'); above the event.preventDefault(); and it also doesn't log to the console so i think it's a problem with the whole code no executing

Answer (score 0):

Check that the event is bound within a `$(document).on('ready' ...` otherwise the event won't fire and the form will just submit normally or not via AJAX.

Your code should look like:

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {
    var request;
    $("#AjaxForm").submit(function(event){

    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);

    // Let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
    // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
    // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

    // Fire off the request to /form.php
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "login.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // Reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

    // Prevent default posting of form
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Note that these callback events are actually deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.

You will also need to ensure that your `POST` and `action` attributes are set on the form in all cases.

Comment: I guess its answer because I tried to exec script in question, (include jQuery, form, script) and it was fine for me, i got `Hooray, it worked!`

Comment: Used this and it does login but it doesn't use ajax because when i comment the ajax out it also submits. And i don't get an alert. Take a look: http://5f6738d9.ngrok.io/test/public/index.html  username is test and password is test

Comment: Where exactly in your source / js files have you got the AJAX code?

Comment: In the html page for now in <script> tags

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#AjaxForm").on("submit",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this);
        var $cacheData = $form.find("input, submit");
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr("action"),
            type: $form.attr("method"),
            data: serializedData,
            xhrFields: {
                onprogress: function(e){
                    $cacheData.prop("disabled", true);
                    console.log(e.loaded / e.total*100 + "%");
                }
            },
            done: function(text){
                if(text == "Succes!"){
                    alert(text);
                } else {
                    alert(text);
                }
            },
            fail: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
            },
            always: function(){
                $cacheData.prop("disabled", false);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This allows you to do some usefull things:

1. You're able to monitor the progress in the console
2. Just because Ajax is succesfull, doesn't mean you can't have an error returned. For example: Wrong password. So now you can simple echo errors back this script will show them. Echo "Succes!" when the login was fine.

Keep in mind though that this script requires that you set the HTML attributes `action` and `method` in your form.

Comment: I don't mind if you downvote my answer. But please explain why so it can be improved.

Comment: I think they did because you are using the deprecated succes and error? I'm not sure but from what i've read i think it's best to use .done .fail and .always now.

Comment: @Lagastic Hmm although that might be it, according to http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ neither are deprecated. Not even an advise to use something different?

Comment: @icecub while I wouldn't downvote anyone (because I have better things to do in life!), there is a yellow box a ways down that page you linked which mentions the deprecation as of jQuery 1.8 for jqXHR.success / error / complete.

Comment: @Ross Thanks! It seems I've missed it. Updated my answer accordingly.